# Faces detected with Haarcascade, how to draw bounding boxes over same faces with different color

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

the code below as I said on topic detects each faces in an image by using haarcascade- Opencv/Python.

[image: Detects and drawing boxes like this]

Code detects all faces,

But I  need to detect SAME faces in an image and then to draw bounding boxes with different colors

[image: I need outpu Like this]

Iam beginer I googled to find how I can do this but I  was inadequate.

I know that I need dataset, but I dont know how to train it and how to implement to the code below..

Does anyone had experinece about this before?

Maybe someone can give me an example according to code below and then I will try to follow his steps.

code that detects faces:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
test_image = cv2.imread("C:\Users\erdal.alimovski\Desktop\faces.jpg")

test_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(test_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(test_image_gray, cmap='gray')

def convertToRGB(image):
return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

haar_cascade_face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\Users\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

faces_rects = haar_cascade_face.detectMultiScale(test_image_gray, scaleFactor = 1.2, minNeighbors = 5);

print('Faces found: ', len(faces_rects))

for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rects:
  cv2.rectangle(test_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("yeni",test_image)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

At line `cv2.rectangle(test_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)`
the parameter (0,255,0) means that you draw everytime a green rectangle (because 255 is the green component).

You could either

1- pass a random-generated color on this parameter

2- init a list of colors that you want to use and loop through it in `for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rects:` like

```
colorList=[(0,255,0),(255,0,0),(0,0,255)] # etc ...
i=0
for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rects:
  cv2.rectangle(test_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), colorList[i], 2)
  i=i+1
```

Comment: ,yes but then it randomly will draw bounding boxes without checking which faces are the  SAME ones..I need algorithm which will check which faces are the same one and then will draw bounnding boxes according to which ones are the same.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. The function you're using only detects the faces on an image. There is no feature memory. You will need to extract the features of each face and then do the recognition. Take a look at eigenfaces or feature descriptiors for faces.